# Function keys not working on MacOs with external Mac keyboard?

Tags: intellij-idea

Example: according to the menu, the keyboard shortcut for `Find Usages` should be *option* F7.

When I use the built-in keyboard, and actually press `fn` + `Shift` + `7` ... it works as expected.

When I use my external Magic 2 Apple keyboard, and press `option` + `F7` ... nothing happens?!

What am I doing wrong?

Update: I just figured that my external keyboard has a `fn` key as well. So when I press `fn` + `option` + `F7` that works. But that is super cumbersome (the `fn` key is to the right of backspace, it is *hard* to press that together with any function key).

Comment: Does https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204436 help?

Comment: @CrazyCoder I *think* it will, when I get a chance to test next week. Feel free to turn that into an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Change the behavior of function keys on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204436) document is probably what you are looking for:

> If you prefer the top row of keys to always behave as standard
>   function keys without holding the Fn key:
>
> 1. Choose System Preferences from the Apple menu.
> 2. Click Keyboard.
> 3. Click the Keyboard tab if it's not already highlighted.
> 4. Select "Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys"

Comment: this is not working for mac os venture with an external keyboard connected, the f keys are simply out of the scope, how can I make them work?

Answer (score -1):

The most useful Function key on a Macbook is F3 ...to jump between multiple screens or windows. However, when you plug in an external keyboard the F3 key does not work as it did on the Macbook (Dell keyboard , F3 is audio increase)
F3 on Macbook is actually "Mission Control" and same functionality can be achieved by hitting "control" (or ^) plus the "up-arrow" key. This may differ from Osx versions but can be confirmed by going to "System" > "Keyboard Shortcuts" > "Mission Control" to see what shortcut is assigned to "Mission Control"

Comment: This very much sounds like some generated answer that has nothing to do with my question. Please clarify/elaborate how it answers the question.